# How can I specify a specific format for morgan in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, morgan

Using morgan/express in nodejs, how can I display the console output in the following format: Day/Month/Year:HH:MM:SS GET/POST "some-api-endpoint-path" ?

I have tried using the "combined" format but have not had much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morgan has a list of predefined tokens that you can find at this [address](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#tokens).

In your case, you want to use `date`, `method` and `url`. Thus your morgan setup will be:

```
app.use(morgan(':date :method ":url"'));
```

This should be enough for you to understand the basics of it and fiddle around to get the best log output for you.

If you want to create a token of your own, you will have to call `morgan.token()`. Here is an example of setting the token `username` using req.user provided by Express and Passport:

```
morgan.token('username', function (req, res) { 
    var username = req.user ? req.user.username: "Guest";
    return username;
});
```

This will make it available as a token for logging and you will be able to call:

```
app.use(morgan(':username :date :method :url'));
```